# Array element is undefined even after pushing elements into it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js

I am building an video saving service as a project and have an array of the user's saved videos obtained from the database `response.array[]`, I then push the `videoId` into an display array `video[]` but on displaying the respective `videoId` using `console.log()` it keeps coming undefined.

I have the code snippet as below.

```
let video = [];
this.service.nextVideo().subscribe( response =>
{
    response.array.forEach(element => {
    video.push(element.videoId);
  });
})
console.log(video[0]); //Output is undefined
```

The full code snippet is like such

```
nxtVideo(){
    let video = [];
    this.service.nextVideo().subscribe( response => 
    {
        response.array.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element.videoId);//Display's video id
          video.push(element.videoId);
        });
    })
    console.log(video[0]); //Output undefined
    console.log(video); //Output shows all elements but on accessing specific elements it shows undefined
    return (video[this.offset++]); //offset is a global variable to measure watched videos
  }

  Launch(){
    let videoId = this.nxtVideo();
    //The Display table starts here
  }
```

Comment: because this seems to be async `console.log(video[0])` is executed before the async call ends

Comment: Possibly because `response` method is asynchronously invoked after `console.log` statement has already been executed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, How do i solve it? 
As i need to return `video[0]` to another variable as this entire snippet comes inside a different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. it must be work, since its asynchronous function.

```
let video = [];
this.service.nextVideo().subscribe( response =>
{
    response.array.forEach(element => {
       video.push(element.videoId);
    });
    console.log(video[0]); //Output is undefined
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need to return `video[0]` to another variable as this entire snippet comes inside a different function.

similar to this `nextVideo = Video();`

and `Video()` is the code snippet.

It may not always be `video[0]` and may be any value let say `video[k]`

Comment: can u give full file?

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks.